# How to grab DOM from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

Above this is my index.html from my chrome extension :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Scrapper</title>
  <style>
    body {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body id="wrapper-extension-scrapper">
  <h1>PMUP Test</h1>
  <button id="run">Run</button>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's basic HTML, but I want to grab my `wrapper-extension-scrapper` identifier

I'm trying to do something like that in my `main.js`

```
window.addEventListener("load", ev => {
  console.log(document.getElementById("wrapper-extension-scrapper"))
});
```

But when I run my chrome extension, he always return null

If you have some advice thanks a lot guys !

Comment: You can use content script access DOM. Please read getting started docs here:https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: You can write an example ? To help other people with the same problem ? @elegant-user